# Python replace special character of many different languages

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, special-characters

I'm reading tables from a website where one of the columns is university name and some of the names have special characters which are the following (but the names are written like I put them here, so is not a task I can fix by reading the web in a different way):

```
['KoÃ§ University', 'Technische UniversitÃ¤t Dresden', 'UniversitÃ¤t fÃ¼r Musik und darstellende Kunst Wien', 'Technische UniversitÃ¤t Wien', 'Ã\x89cole Nationale SupÃ©rieure des Beaux-Arts, Paris', 'Universidad SimÃ³n BolÃ\xadvar (USB)', 'PontifÃ\xadcia Universidade CatÃ³lica do Rio Grande do Sul (PUCRS)', 'BogaziÃ§i Ã\x9cniversitesi', 'UniversitÃ\xa0 degli Studi di Udine', 'Universitat AutÃ²noma de Barcelona', 'UniversitÃ© de Rennes 1', 'Ã\x89cole Normale SupÃ©rieure de Lyon', 'Ã\x89cole Nationale SupÃ©rieure de CrÃ©ation Industrielle, ENSCI Les Ateliers', 'UniversitÃ¤t Bremen', 'Institut National des Sciences AppliquÃ©es de Lyon (INSA)', 'UniversitÃ© Laval', 'UniversitÃ¤t des Saarlandes', 'UniversitÃ¤t Konstanz', 'Philipps-UniversitÃ¤t Marburg ', 'El Colegio de MÃ©xico, A.C.', 'Humboldt-UniversitÃ¤t zu Berlin', 'PontifÃ\xadcia Universidade CatÃ³lica do Rio de Janeiro', 'Universidade Federal do ParanÃ¡ - UFPR', 'UniversitÃ¤t Potsdam', 'USI - UniversitÃ  della Svizzera italiana', 'PalackÃ½ University Olomouc', 'CentraleSupÃ©lec', 'Arts et MÃ©tiers, ParisTech', 'UniversitÃ© de Sherbrooke', 'UniversitÃ\xa0 degli studi Roma Tre', 'WestfÃ¤lische Wilhelms-UniversitÃ¤t MÃ¼nster ', 'Universidad PolitÃ©cnica de Madrid (UPM)', 'Universidad Adolfo IbÃ\xa0Ã±ez ', 'Ã\x89cole Centrale de Lille', 'UniversitÃ© Paris 13 Nord', 'UniversitÃ  degli Studi di Udine', 'Universidade Federal de SÃ£o Paulo', 'Instituto Nacional de MatemÃ¡tica Pura e Aplicada (IMPA)', 'UniversitÃ¤t Mannheim', 'UniversitÃ© Toulouse 1 Capitole', 'Technische UniversitÃ¤t Braunschweig', 'Eberhard Karls UniversitÃ¤t TÃ¼bingen', 'UniversitÃ¤t Rostock', 'UniversitÃ© Grenoble Alpes', 'UniversitÃ© de Fribourg', 'UniversitÃ¤t Innsbruck', 'Universidad Adolfo IbÃ Ã±ez ', 'UniversitÃ© du QuÃ©bec', 'Universidad de la RepÃºblica (Udelar)', 'Universitat PolitÃ¨cnica de Catalunya Â· BarcelonaTech (UPC)', 'UniversitÃ¤t Regensburg', 'UniversitÃ© de Paris', 'UniversitÃ© Paris 1 PanthÃ©on-Sorbonne ', 'Universidad TÃ©cnica Federico Santa MarÃ\xada (USM)', 'Ruprecht-Karls-UniversitÃ¤t Heidelberg', 'Pontificia Universidad CatÃ³lica Argentina', 'UniversitÃ\xa0Â\xa0di Padova', 'Technische UniversitÃ¤t Berlin (TU Berlin)', 'UniversitÃ¤t Stuttgart', 'FundaÃ§Ã£o Getulio Vargas (FGV)', 'Universidade de SÃ£o Paulo', 'Universidad Nacional AutÃ³noma de MÃ©xico  (UNAM)', 'Universidade Federal de SÃ£o Carlos (UFSCar)', 'Ã\x89cole Centrale de Nantes', 'Technische UniversitÃ¤t Kaiserslautern', 'UniversitÃ  degli studi Roma Tre', 'Pontificia Universidad CatÃ³lica del PerÃº', 'UniversitÃ\xa0 degli Studi di Pavia', 'UniversitÃ© PSL', 'UniversitÃ© de MontrÃ©al ', 'Pontificia Universidad CatÃ³lica de ValparaÃ\xadso', 'University Paris 2 PanthÃ©on-Assas', 'UniversitÃ© Paris-Nanterre', 'Universidad AutÃ³noma de San Luis de PotosÃ\xad', 'UniversitÃ¤t  Leipzig', 'Ruhr-UniversitÃ¤t Bochum', 'UniversitÃ© LumiÃ¨re Lyon 2', 'UniversitÃ© de Lille', 'UniversitÃ© Claude Bernard Lyon 1', 'UniversitÃ© catholique de Louvain (UCLouvain)', 'UniversitÃ©  de Technologie, Troyes (UTT)', 'Universidad de San AndrÃ©s - UdeSA', 'Martin-Luther-UniversitÃ¤t Halle-Wittenberg', 'University of TromsÃ¸ The Arctic University of Norway', 'Rheinische Friedrich-Wilhelms-UniversitÃ¤t Bonn', 'Universidad de AlcalÃ¡', 'USI - UniversitÃ\xa0 della Svizzera italiana', 'LinkÃ¶ping University', 'Universidad Nacional de CÃ³rdoba - UNC', 'UniversitÃ\xa0 degli Studi di Perugia', 'UniversitÃ  degli Studi di Pavia', 'Johannes Gutenberg UniversitÃ¤t Mainz', 'UniversitÃ  Iuav di Venezia', 'Friedrich-Alexander-UniversitÃ¤t Erlangen-NÃ¼rnberg', 'UniversitÃ© de Nantes', 'Universidad de CÃ³rdoba', 'Universidade de BrasÃ\xadlia', 'UniversitÃ© de Strasbourg', 'Universidad AutÃ³noma de Nuevo LeÃ³n', 'Pontificia Universidad CatÃ³lica de Chile (UC)', 'UniversitÃ© Paris-Est CrÃ©teil Val de Marne', 'Universidad AutÃ³noma del Estado de MÃ©xico (UAEMex)', 'UniversitÃ© de Montpellier', 'UniversitÃ¤t der KÃ¼nste Berlin', 'UniversitÃ Â di Padova', 'UniversitÃ© Paris-Saclay', 'EÃ¶tvÃ¶s LorÃ¡nd University', 'Technische UniversitÃ¤t Bergakademie Freiberg', 'Technische UniversitÃ¤t Hamburg', 'Universidade CatÃ³lica Portuguesa - UCP', 'Ã\x89cole Nationale SupÃ©rieure des Industries Chimiques (ENSIC), Nancy', 'Instituto TecnolÃ³gico AutÃ³nomo de MÃ©xico (ITAM)', 'UniversitÃ© de Limoges', 'UniversitÃ© Sorbonne Nouvelle Paris 3', 'UniversitÃ© Paul Sabatier Toulouse III', 'Julius-Maximilians-UniversitÃ¤t WÃ¼rzburg', 'UniversitÃ© de Poitiers', 'Universitat PolitÃ¨cnica de ValÃ¨ncia', 'UniversitÃ\xa0Â\xa0Cattolica del Sacro Cuore', 'UniversitÃ© Nice Sophia Antipolis', 'University of JyvÃ¤skylÃ¤', "Haute Ecole d\\'art et de design de GenÃ¨ve (HEAD)", 'Bauhaus-UniversitÃ¤t Weimar', 'UniversitÃ© de LiÃ¨ge', 'UniversitÃ¤t Jena', 'University of GÃ¶ttingen', 'Technische UniversitÃ¤t Ilmenau', 'Ã\x89cole Centrale de Lyon', 'Ludwig-Maximilians-UniversitÃ¤t MÃ¼nchen', 'UniversitÃ© de Lorraine', 'UniversitÃ© de Technologie de CompiÃ¨gne (UTC)', "UniversitÃ© CÃ´te d\\'Azur", 'UniversitÃ¤t Siegen', 'UniversitÃ¤t Duisburg-Essen', 'UniversitÃ© de Savoie, Chambery, Annecy', 'Universidad AutÃ³noma de Madrid', 'UniversitÃ Â Cattolica del Sacro Cuore', 'Ankara Ã\x9cniversitesi', 'Universidade da CoruÃ±a ', 'UniversitÃ  degli Studi di Perugia', 'Hochschule fÃ¼r Gestaltung und Kunst ZÃ¼rich', 'UniversitÃ¤t Hamburg']
```

I want to transform this special characters to their original forms, I mean: Å, ö, ü, ã, á, è, ê, etc.
I know that I have to do some encoding and decoding this special character, but I don't get it.
I tried the following code but it doesn't fix them:

```
special_string.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

Does anyone know how to make this change in all the different "encoding" languages? maybe is there a library for this task?

Comment: Likely the error happens in that first step, "reading tables from a website". You're somehow not treating that website in the correct encoding, corrupting the characters in the process. If you read them correctly, you wouldn't need to fix them afterwards.

Comment: This is one of the websites `https://www.topuniversities.com/university-rankings/university-subject-rankings/2019/engineering-civil-structural` you can filter by Dresden and you will se that is written the word  `Technische UniversitÃ¤t Dresden`. That's what I mean when say that the words are written like that in the website...

Comment: So it's actually already corrupted in the original data?! ‍♂️ Then you may have a hard time fixing all possible records automatically, as they may all be corrupted in different ways.

Comment: Encoding the string to UTF-8 and then decoding can't fix your problem. If the original data hasn't been corrupted, you may be able to take the data as a byte array and then `.decode('utf-8)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Deceze has commented, if the data is corrupted at source there is no guarantee that you can undo the corruption.  However, using the data you provided we can make some progress.

Firstly, the vast majority of the strings in your list can be fixed by encoding as latin-1 and then decoding as UTF-8.

```py
>>> s = 'Technische UniversitÃ¤t Dresden'
>>> s.encode('latin').decode('utf-8')
'Technische Universität Dresden'
```

These strings cannot be decoded in this manner:

```
USI - UniversitÃ  della Svizzera italiana
UniversitÃ  degli Studi di Udine
Universidad Adolfo IbÃ Ã±ez 
UniversitÃ  degli studi Roma Tre
UniversitÃ  degli Studi di Pavia
UniversitÃ  Iuav di Venezia
UniversitÃ Â di Padova
UniversitÃ Â Cattolica del Sacro Cuore
UniversitÃ  degli Studi di Perugia
```

It's notable that all but one of these are Italian universities.  The Italian for "university" is "università".  Let's try to corrupt it by doing the reverse of our "fix":

```py
>>> s = 'Università'
>>> s.encode('utf-8').decode('latin')
'UniversitÃ\xa0'
```

You can see we get the "UniversitÃ" that we see in the unfixed names plus `'\xa0'`, which is the non-breaking space character - this character might be stripped by the website or your scraping tool, leading to the Italian names being extra-corrupt.  The easiest way to fix these is probably to replace 'Ã' with 'à' before attempting to fix them.

That leaves just 'Universidad Adolfo IbÃ Ã±ez', which we think ought to be "Universidad Adolfo Ibáñez".  Let's "corrupt" it:

```py
>>> "Universidad Adolfo Ibáñez".encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
'Universidad Adolfo IbÃ¡Ã±ez'
```

This looks the same as the version in the list except that the inverted exclamation mark character has been replaced by a space.  We can reinstate it to fix our string.

```py
>>> s = 'Universidad Adolfo IbÃ Ã±ez'
>>> bs = s.encode('latin-1')
>>> fixed = bs.replace(b'\xc3 ', b'\xc3\xa1').decode('utf-8')
>>> fixed
'Universidad Adolfo Ibáñez'
```